# Photo icon preview from SMB network share

Tags: networking

Using 0.4 Loki, if I browse 'entire network' to my SMB servers, it defaults to connection by ftp. In this case jpg files don't have an icon preview, and if the file is loaded from the network share, it won't display (although the photo editor opens). The same file copied to local storage previews and opens ok.

Forcing a SMB (window share) connection to the same server, the jpg files now do open correctly, but still have no icon preview.